# how I can Get FAT table from usb device using C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, usb, fat

How I can obtain the FAT table from USB devices using C?, I was googling I have seen that it is possible to get different sectors searching blocks in /dev/ but I would need the whole FAT table

Comment: someone has any approach?

Comment: `open()` the raw device in `/dev/`, `lseek()` to relevant offset and  `read()`.